# Mac Terminal Wont Open When I'm Using QT Creator Anymore

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal, qt-creator

Before I updated both QT and Xcode on my mac, my computer just stopped opening up the terminal when I went to run my code. It had worked for months and is still enabled as my default on QT. I Tried uninstalling and reinstalling both QT and Xcode, but my terminal still will not open when I run the code. When I disable terminal as my default, I can see my output at the bottom of my screen in QT, but I would like it to open in terminal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on https://forum.qt.io found the solution, thank's so much to him !
A .dmg archive with a corrected QtCreator version 7.0.1 from the snapshot downloads is available here: https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qtcreator_qt5/7.0/7.0.1/134/
After installation, the terminal opens correctly